# Xamarin C# Take picture without open Camera

Tags: c#, android, image, xamarin, cross-platform

I have a QrCodeCode with used the libary "Zxing". Now i want to Take a picture of the complete screen inside the QrCodeScanner. The Problem is i dont want to open the Camera. I want to create a Button that just takes a picture.

I Tried to use the Media.Plugin but this one leav's my App and that is not my goal.

**EDIT**

as best zxing just should capture my actual screen.

Comment: Do you want the button click to take a picture through the camera without seeing a preview of what the camera shows? Or do you want to take a screenshot of the screen? Anyway, it would be good if you show what code you have right now and which part of it is not working correctly or doing what you want to achieve.

Comment: i have a preview inside my QrCodeSanner. I just want to Capture this without open camera. Actually i have not a code because everything i tried was opening the camera app and that is not my goal.